# Can I enable/disable mobile data from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a today extension for iOS. In the storyboard I want a switch that turns on or off my mobile data on my iOS device. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: it is the end-users' privileges and they can do it in the _iOS Settings_ only; what you can do in your app is to redirect the user to your own apps setting's page in _iOS Settings_ and to ask them to turn the mobile data on for your app.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. However, you can use an alert view that  takes the user to the device settings:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```